# ggplot2 code stopped working in 3.3.x

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code works in `R 3.0.2` but when I try to run the code in  `3.3.1` I get the error `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): x, y`. I've tried reading the documentation on `aes` but I wasn't able to fix it. How do I update my code to work in `3.3.1`?

```
library(ggplot2)
V<-c(4.1,4.9,5.78,6.83,7.79,8.93,9.82)


I<-c(4,4.92,5.8,6.86,7.82,8.93,9.86)*(1E-3)


lm0<-lm(I~V+0)

lsrl0<-function(V) lm0$coef[1]*V

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(3E-3, 10E-3)),y=c(3.5,10),aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=lsrl0,linetype='twodash',color='blue')+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(c(V,I)), aes(x = V, y = I),
             shape=21,size=3.5,color='dark blue',fill='light blue')+
  xlim(3,10)+theme_bw()
```

Comment: I think you mean to use `data.frame(V, I)`, not `data.frame(c(V, I))`.

Comment: Your data frame in `geom_point` is one column

Comment: Hm, that worked, I wonder why earlier versions of  `R` didn't like that? Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: `data.frame(x=c(3E-3, 10E-3)),y=c(3.5,10)` is this also on purpose? The parenthesis seems misplaced, i'd write`data.frame(x=c(3E-3, 10E-3),y=c(3.5,10))`

Comment: @Haboryme The data there doesn't do anything at all. You could very well do `ggplot(data.frame(1), aes(1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, is this the desired output (instead of using c(V,I) for geom_point just use (V,I) for the data frame, was there a typo)?

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(3E-3, 10E-3)),y=c(3.5,10),aes(x)) + 
      stat_function(fun=lsrl0,linetype='twodash',color='blue')+
      geom_point(data=data.frame(V,I), aes(x = V, y = I),
                 shape=21,size=3.5,color='dark blue',fill='light blue')+
      xlim(3,10)+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This works! I wonder why it worked anyway in the older version?